# L-Value required? C programming bit pattern

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, lvalue

```
void InsertA(SET *A,int elem)
{
    if( isMember(*A,elem) == false)
    {
    *A = *A || 1<<elem;; /*it says its in this row*/
    }
}
```

/*Error: Lvalue required in Function InsertA
any thoughts on this guys? noob here

*/

Comment: check operator precedence (in other words - parenthesis are your friends). Also make sure that the error is indeed in the line you indicated (I just compiled your code - works ok in MSVC++ 2010 once I removed the `isMember` and replaced `SET` with `int`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement :

```
*A = *A || 1<<elem;; /*it says its in this row*/
```

We have these operators `*,=,||,<<`

Now look at the precedence table at

```
Precedence    Operator   operation                  associativity 
               --------   ---------                 ----------------
3                  *       Indirection (dereference)       R to L
7                  <<       Bitwise left shift             L to R
14                 ||       Logical OR                     L to R
16                 =       Direct assignment               R to L
```

So lets see what happens:

1) Indirection will be performed first. There are two of them. They associate Right to Left. That means Right one will be performed first. Its important to understand that there are two dereferencing operator here which will be considered differently later when encountering the `=` operator.

2) A bit wise left shift will performed on 1.
3) A logical OR will be performed with `*A` and the result of bitwise shift. it may evaluate zero or non zero. 
4) This zero/nonzero value will be assigned to `*A`. Here `*A` can be treated as lvalue in a context of `=` operator. If you leave this consideration it will lead to ambiguity. Because we often think of dereferencing operation like `*A` as an `rvalue` or an `value` to be used. Actually its a valid `lvalue` which will be converted implicitly to a `rvalue` (This is when a `value` which is stored at address pointed by `A` is returned). Otherwise `*A` is simply a container in memory which is open to values.

So the thing is your expression is undefined and does not make any sense why you are putting a **logical** value into `*A`. It will make more sense if you use binary `or` instead of logical.

Lets do that:

We have a new entry in our precedence table

```
Precedence OP   OPeration        Associativity 
12         |    Bitwise OR          L to R
```

Only change will occur in step 3 when a bitwise OR will be performed.

Lets have an example

lets say `elem = 3.`
A is pointing to the array `{1,2,3,3,4}`

1) '*A's will be performed. It will just calculate the "Offsets" needed to do `load` or `store` instructions of the processor.

2)we will get a constant bit pattern : `1 << 3 = 1000`
3)now for `|` we need `rvalues` as both operands. So now a `load` instruction will be performed to fetch the value stored in the memory. Say its `2`. So we will get `0010 | 1000 = 1010`
4)A store instruction will be performed to put this bit pattern into the memory so the array will look like `{1,A,3,3,4}`

Explanation for too much verbosity: I think this can help if future users who will try to find how to dissect a complicated expression by language rules.

Comment: thank you for answering, and sorry for the late reply, i always forget to check back on stackoverflow, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the code should compile. 
But it looks like you want to set a bit in an `int`, so I suspect, you really want `|` instead of `||`.
So you should do

```
*A |= 1<<elem;
```

Comment: thanks for the replies mates really appreciate it, im debugging right now, i just need some ideas not really answers, thanks again :)

Comment: I beg to differ. The code should not compile. 1) SET is undefined 2) isMember() is undefined 3) false is undefined. And yes: the OP probably wants `|=`.

Comment: uhm it's just a snippet of the whole program 1,2,3 is already define :)

Answer (score 0):

|| is a logical operation, not a bitwise one. Have you tried changing it to |?

Whenever you do A = you have the potential to create a temporary A, same with *A. Be careful about using the = operator and look up how to disable copy constructors.

You may use the |= operator. A |= (1 << whatever)

EDIT: make sure you're not compiling your C code with a C++ compiler in C++ mode. GCC has a switch for C, it depends on your build environment.

Comment: It's C, not C++, so no worrying about copy constructors.

Comment: @DanielFischer indeed, but it may be compiled with a C++ compiler. people often write C and compile it with C++ enabled. a struct may then have an auto-generated copy-constructor.

Comment: Also true, compiling C with a C++ compiler causes loads of potential problems.

Comment: ... the best way to avoid these problems is by *not* compiling c with a c++ compiler.